# Calling pdflatex in windows stops with no output

Tags: pdftex

When I invoke `pdflatex "filename.tex"`, only this will be shown and it stops.

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly a corrupt installation as you never even get to the first line from processing any kind of format or input file.

Comment: In command prompt write "pdflatex somthing.tex"

Comment: Reinstall MikTeX.

Comment: did but did not work

Comment: also just try `pdlatex something` (no.tex)

Comment: Your pdftex version looks quite old. Which source for the miktex installation did you use?

Comment: I download from official site "http://miktex.org/download" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If »something.tex« includes packages which are not locally installed, the MiKTeX package manager will try to install them on the fly, at least as far as I remember. If the capacity of your line is small, this can take hours.

Please try an easy example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello pdfTeX!
\end{document}
```

Does this work?

If not, would you please open a command line (»cmd.exe«) and navigate to the folder with this minimal tex file. Once there, type `pdflatex "filename.tex"` and please make a screenshot of the (black) window, as soon as the window freezes. Screenshot: usually there is the snipping tool on windows to do that.

Comment: no . same problem

Comment: @RobiulIslam OK, I edited my text, see above.